# Types of amplifier

Tags: amplifier

Can briefly explain the difference of class A, B and C amplifier and their pros and cons ?
Besides, what is the application and example of circuit for each class amplifier ?

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_amplifier ?

Comment: Far too broad a question for here, especially the request for circuits. There are plenty of references available on the topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think of the final output stage of a power amplifier.  It must be possible to actively drive the output high and low.  This is usually done with some sort of variable pass element (transistor in practise) between the output and the high supply, and the output and the low supply.  Very simplified, the final output stage conceptually looks like this:

[image]

where the proper control circuitry can be thought of as diddling the variable resistors as needed so that the output is driven to the desired voltage.  In practise the pass elements are usually transistors and can look more like current sources or have other characteristics than pure resistance, but that doesn't matter for the discussion of amplifier classes.  Whether they are variable current sources, variable resistances, or something else is actually indistiguishable because they are adjusted as necessary by using feedback to achieve the desired output voltage.

### Class A

Consider the problem of how to use the two pass elements together.  The simple conceptual solution might be to vary each one over its full range accross the output full range.  This would be high quality since the output would naturally follow the desired level to a good extent even without feedback.  For example, if both resistors are equal, then the output will be in the middle, when R1 is 1/4 of R2, then the output will be half way to V+.  You get a nice proportional response over the whole range.  This is basically a class A amplifier.

Now consider the drawback of this method.  You realize that when you want to pull the output high, turning on R2 at all is just a waste of power.  The current to the output has to flow thru R1, but any additional current that flows thru R2 only heats the resistors.  For small signal amplifiers this is often not a big deal, and the control simplicity and the resulting high quality make class A worth it.  However, when you're putting out 10s of watts into a low impedance load like a loudspeaker, the wasted power can be significant.  It's not the cost of the power so much, but the cost of the infrastructure to deal with the heat in the pass elements.

### Class B

So now you have the bright idea that you'll only use R1 to drive the output during the high part of the waveform and R2 during the low part.  In each case, the other resistor is off or very high.  Yes, that's more efficient, but it's also harder to control and doesn't as easily get you a nice proprotional output response without more feedback.  Feedback can cover up some non-linearities in the final output circuit, but only to a extent and often at the cost of other hidden distortions, like intermodulation distortion.  In particular the problem will be to exactly overlap turning one resistor off and starting to turn on the other as the output signal crosses 0.  This is such a common and well known problem of class B amplifiers that it has it's own name, called *crossover distortion*.

### Class AB

Your next bright idea might be to say you're willing to give up a little efficiency to keep both resistor on a little near the middle.  Yes, that makes the handoff between driving the two resistors easier and helps with crossover distortion at the expense of a bit less efficiency.  The more you do this, the more efficiency you give up, with the limiting case being you're back to a pure class A amplifier.  Another way to look at class A is that the blending region extends over the whole output range.  This partially on near the middle method is used sometimes and is called class AB.

### Class C

Class C is something completely different and not applicable to audio amplifiers at all.  Here is a simple concpetual example of a class C output stage:

[image]

The point here is that resonance is exploited to efficiently produce a signal of known frequency.  The switch would normally be a transistor that is turned on hard for a small fraction of the output cycle.  This "kicks" the tank circuit formed by C1 and L1, which then resonates on its own to make the rest of that output cycle until the process is repeated.  This can be quite efficient.  Note that none of the three components shown dissipate any power in the ideal case.  In practise there will be losses, or course, particularly in the inevitable resistive component of the real inductor.

This circuit must be tuned for the particular single output frequency it is intended to produce.  Note that C1 and L1 will only resonate together at one particular frequency.  So class C is very efficient, but only when you want a single known frequency out.  This is the case with commercial radio transmitters, for example, and the final output stage is often a class C amplifier or largely based on one.

### Class D

You didn't ask, but class D is something you hear about a lot nowadays, and is becoming quite popular including for power audio use.  Class D is essentially a switching power supply that can actively drive both high and low.  There are two switches before the inductor, one that connects it to the positive supply and one that connects it to the negative supply.  By carefully adjusting for each pulse what fraction of the time the high side switch is on and what fraction for the low side switch, you can make the output follow some desired signal.  Of course for this to work, the switching frequency needs to be at least a few times higher than the highest frequency of interest in the output signal.  Fortunately that is doable today with the fast transistors and control circuits available.  Even "high fi" audio only goes to 20 kHz upper frequency.  Switching power supplies routinely operate at 10x or more of that, so this is all doable.  Note that just like for the class C case, none of the parts ideally dissipate any power.  In parctise of course there are real losses, but class C is today the highest efficiency means to get a arbitrary power output signal, as long as it is band limited to a acceptable level.